# What is the difference between `after_create` and `after_save` and when to use which?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Are `after_create` and `after_save` the same as per functionality?

I want to do an operation with the email of a user after its account creation.

I want to do that operation when it is saved in the database.

which is preferable to use:  `after_create` or `after_save`?

Answer (score 225, accepted):

`after_create` only works once - just after the record is first created.

`after_save` works every time you save the object - even if you're just updating it many years later

So if you want to do this email operation only just the once (and then never again) then use `after_create`.

If you want to do it *every* time the object is saved, then do it in `after_save`

Comment: readers should note that, [according to the docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-update_all), ActiveRecord's `update_all` does not invoke any callbacks, including `after_*`

Answer (score 97):

From [the docs](http://ar.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html):

> **`after_create()`**
>
> Is called after
>   `Base.save` on new objects that haven‘t
>   been saved yet (no record exists).
>
> **`after_save()`**
>
> Is called after `Base.save`
>   (regardless of whether it‘s a create
>   or update save).

Answer (score 1):

```
after_save()
```

Works fine when you have to save models that do not save very often.
For this particular example of changing records frequently it would be advisable to use

```
 after_commit()
```

make sure that the model is saved in the database before the action is executed
   **after_commit :calculate_credit_score**

```
def calculate_credit_score
     #Call a Cron job
end
```

Comment: You advise to use `after_commit` but don't explain why. Please can you elaborate? Note that `after_commit` runs on create, updat and destroy. Docs: https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods/after_commit
So it is not the same behavior as `after_save` You really want to call that cron_job after after destroying the record? Or in the ops case, send an email to a now deleted user? Be careful with using `after_commit`

Comment: `after_commit` runs on those CRUD operations, so if in his case the email is updated often, then it would be easier to combine the action for a specific callback.

In my case I used
`after_commit : calculate_profile_update, on: :update`