# How to properly hook into after_create in Rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I currently have something like this:

```
class Article

  # fields = [flag, something]

  after_create :update_flag

  def update_flag
    self.flag = 1 if something_changed?
  end
end
```

But it doesn't change the 'flag' field when I change the something field. I've saved the object. Still no changes.

```
a = Article.create(flag: 0, something: "content")
a.something = "different"
a.save

a.flag
> 0
```

Any ideas?

Comment: 6 years! haha it is funny looking back on your complete lack of understanding :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change

```
after_create
```

to

```
after_update
```

In your code example you're updating the object and that's the reason why you need a different hook. Please see [docs](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#available-callbacks) for further information.

Comment: Thank you very much, that worked. I was confused because I thought after_create hook was run whenever an object was initialized. I see I need to learn my hooks. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

```
after_create()
```

Is called after  Base.save on new objects that haven‘t been saved yet (no record exists).

after_save()

Is called after Base.save (regardless of whether it‘s a create or update save).`

Answer (score 0):

Change "after_create" to "after_save" because after_create only works once - just after the record is first created & after_save works every time you save the object - even if you're just updating it many years later.

Reference- [What is the difference between `after_create` and `after_save` and when to use which?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6422199/what-is-the-difference-between-after-create-and-after-save-and-when-to-use-w)