# How does after_save work when saving an object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

If I do the following:

```
@user.name = "John"    
@user.url = "www.john.com"
@user.save
```

If I use `after_save`

```
@user.url = "www.johnseena.com"
@user.save
```

What will happen when I do this?

I believe it should save the value because of the 'after_save' callback.

Comment: Are you really using instance variable `@user` in `after_save` callback?

Comment: You've really got to work on explaining what you need a little better and give some more examples of what you have tried.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

In my opinion, if you call `save` function in a `after_save` callback, then it will trap into a recursion unless you put a guard at the beginning. like this

```
class User < AR::Base
      after_save :change_url

      def change_url
          #Check some condition to skip saving
          url = "www.johnseena.com"
          save              #<======= this save will fire the after_save again
      end
end
```

However, apart from putting a guard, you can use `update_column` also

```
def change_url
    update_column(:url, "www.johnseena.com")
end
```

In this case it will not fire `after_save`. However, it will fire `after_update`. So if you have any update operation on that call back then you are in recursion again :)

Comment: Great way to explain Thanks for your time.

Comment: NOTE: `#update_column` actually [skips callbacks](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-update_columns).

Answer (score 8):

The **after_save** callback will be triggered irrespective its a **save** or an **update** on that object.

Also,

**update_column** doesn't trigger any callbacks(ie after_update) and skips validations too. see http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/update_column

U should specifically use **after_create** or **after_update** depending upon the operation and its timing.

```
after_create :send_mail
def send_x_mail
  #some mail that user has been created
end

after_update :send_y_mail
def send_y_mail
  #some data has been updated
end

after_save :update_some_date
def update_some_data
  ...
  action which doesnt update the current object else will trigger the call_back
end
```

Also see [What is the difference between `after_create` and `after_save` and when to use which?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6422199/what-is-the-difference-between-after-create-and-after-save-and-when-to-use-w) and for callbacks see http://ar.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html#M000059

Comment: `after_update` and `before_update` are both exist as of rails 4.1 . You can check the complete list of available callbacks from [Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#available-callbacks)

Answer (score 4):

If you modify anything int the `after_save` it won't be saved, as the `save` is already taken place. The only chance to intervene is to rollback the whole transaction. If you add another `save` in the `after_save`, then it will be an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of performing two queries to the database and worrying about recursion, you may want to consider just modifying the data payload before it goes to the server.

```
class User < AR::Base
      before_save :change_url

      def change_url
          url = "www.johnseena.com"
      end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks to everyone who helped me out here. Here is the solution which solved my problem. I modified by order model to the following:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_and_belongs_to_many :users

  validates :item, presence: true

  def add_order(username, order)
    user = User.where(username: username).first
    if !user.nil?
      user.orders.create(item: order.item)
    end
  end

  def remove_order(order)
  end

end
```