# Rails after_save method trying to update record over and over

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods, model, open-uri

I'm having a weird issue, my app seem to get stuck in a loop.

I have a model called Pages which allows the user to input a URL on save I have a after_save method called process_pages which looks as follows

### pages.rb (model)

```
class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
  require 'open-uri'

  after_save :process_pages

  def process_pages
    self.html = open(self.url).read
    self.save
  end 
end
```

On saving the URL I can see in the development console that it get the HTML of the site but tries to constantly save the record over and over again stalling the page and I have to manually exit the server.

When I start back up again the record has been added and works as expected until I add another URL?

Is there anything wrong with my code which might be causing this continuous loop?

Thanks for reading!

Comment: There are plenty of workarounds in the answers, but I want to point out that you're experiencing this issue because your model is doing way too much. If you treat your model as an interface to your database and not as a dumping ground for business logic that might get accessed outside of a controller, you will end up creating leaner objects that don't trip on themselves (and each other).

Comment: Thanks @coreyward Am i right in saying then this method should be taking place somewhere else in my project?

Comment: Yes, absolutely. Rails provides a lot of rope and encourages you to hang yourself, unfortunately. For this particular behavior, you would probably be best served by creating separate objects to handle fetching content for the page (which will also help with mocking/stubbing for tests as well as enabling background processing very readily) and for handling updating an instance of `Page` with the content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to call `process_pages` **only once** after **Creating a `Page` record** and not after Updating a Page record then I would suggest to use `after_create` instead.

```
class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
  require 'open-uri'

  after_create :process_pages

  def process_pages
    self.html = open(self.url).read
    self.save
  end 
end
```

With `after_save :process_pages`, `process_pages` method would be called every time you save a Page record. You are saving a Page record again within `process_pages` method which triggers the `after_save` callback and you start looping.

See this SO Question for **[difference between after_save and after_create](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6422199/what-is-the-difference-between-after-create-and-after-save-and-when-to-use-w)**.
You will understand better as to why you are going in loops.

Comment: Note however that this will not update html field if you change the url after the model is being saved for the first time.

Comment: @BroiSatse +1 I now included that point explicitly in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

This is because you are resaving it all the time. Instead do:

```
def process_pages
  update_column(:html, open(self.url).read)
end
```

`update_column` is saving one column to the database skipping all the callbacks, so it won't retrigger your after_save callback. It is however pretty pointless to do two queries while you can do one with `before_save` filter:

```
before_save :process_pages

def process_pages
  self.html = open(self.url).read
end
```

But probably best way to go with is overriding setter for `url` method:

```
def url=(value)
  super
  self.html = open(self.url).read
end
```

This way you can use page html before the model is saved.

Answer (score 3):

You are stuck in a loop because your callback is triggered **after save**, and then the method definition itself is calling **save**, causing the callback to fire again.

You have some options. You can change the callback to `before_save`.

```
class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
  require 'open-uri'

  before_save :process_pages

  def process_pages
    self.html = open(self.url).read
  end 
end
```

You can change to an `after_create` callback that only fires once the record is created and not updated, but this may not be desired behaviour.

You can also skip the callbacks by calling `update_column` instead of calling `save` as pointed out by [@BroiSatse](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22674728/276959)

Answer (score 0):

So does self.url point back to the pages url?  If so, when you save it, it hits your server for the page, which might cause another save and another url request, etc.