# Rails RSpec feature test failing due to nil value, model test passing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I am running into an issue with model tests and feature tests in rails 5.1.6. 
My model schema looks like

```
create_table "links", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string "link_title"
  t.string "link_url"
  t.integer "upvotes", default: 0, null: false
  t.integer "downvotes", default: 0, null: false
  ...
end
```

my link model file

```
class Link < ApplicationRecord
  def self.hottest_first
    Link.all.sort_by(&:score).reverse
  end

  def score
    upvotes - downvotes
  end
end
```

and my controller looks like

```
class LinksController < ApplicationController
  def index
     @links = Link.all.hottest_first
  end
end
```

When I run my test suite all other tests including model test pass, but this feature test fails.

```
 RSpec.feature "User submits a link" do
   scenario "they see the page for the submitted link" do
   link_title = "This Testing Rails book is awesome!"
   link_url = "http://testingrailsbook.com"

   visit root_path
   click_on "Submit a new link"
   fill_in "Link title", with: link_title
   fill_in "Link url", with: link_url
   click_on 'Submit!'

   expect(page).to have_link link_title, href: link_url
 end
```

and the error I get is

```
 User submits a link they see the page for the submitted link
    Failure/Error: upvotes - downvotes

 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `-' for nil:NilClass
 # ./app/models/link.rb:18:in `score'
 # ./app/models/link.rb:6:in `sort_by'
 # ./app/models/link.rb:6:in `hottest_first'
 # ./app/controllers/links_controller.rb:3:in `index'
```

I have no idea why this would only fail this test but pass in my model tests or any other test that is looking at either my API or Index, All other tests pass, If I look at the console it shows that downvotes and upvotes are both equal to 0 and not nil. Any help would be great.

Comment: FWIW, sorting this way pulls ALL link records into memory, then sorts them in an array. You'd get much better performance if you let the database do the sorting for you: `Link.all.order('upvotes - downvotes DESC')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`default: 0` in the schema applies to the database column. This value is being assigned *upon the record is being saved to the database*.

The method `score` in your model is called on unsaved `link`. Until saved, it does not magically have `upvotes` and `downvotes` columns initialized.

You have two opportunities: either implement [`after_create`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6422199/what-is-the-difference-between-after-create-and-after-save-and-when-to-use-w#6422221) callback in your model, initializing both `upvotes` and `downvotes` to zero values or simply:

```
def score
  upvotes.to_i - downvotes.to_i
end
```

Since `nil.to_i == 0`, you are all set and I believe test is to pass.